# сравнение двух date objects

Tags: javascript

У меня есть два input type date, где выставлена сегодняшняя дата и завтрашняя

```
  const today = new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10);
const currentDate = new Date()
const myDay = new Date(currentDate)
myDay.setDate(myDay.getDate() + 1)
const tomorrow = myDay.toISOString().substr(0, 10);

document.getElementById('checkin_date').value = today;
document.getElementById('checkout_date').value = tomorrow;
```

и две дате в джсоне(имитация сервера) в таком виде:

```
   "reservedFrom": "2020-02-01T23:28:56.782Z",
    "reservedTo": "2020-01-29T23:28:56.782Z"
```

и мне нужно их сравнить. Как я это делаю

```
  let room  = data.filter(room => {
let checkinDate= new Date(today);                                  
let checkoutDate = new Date(tomorrow);                   
let reservedFromData = new Date(room.reservedFrom);                  
let reservedToData = new Date(room.reservedTo);
let isAvaliable =  wasNotSet || (parseInt(checkinDate.valueOf() / 1000) <= parseInt(reservedFromData.valueOf() / 1000)) || (parseInt(checkinDate.valueOf() / 1000) >= parseInt(reservedToData.valueOf() / 1000)) && (parseInt(checkoutDate.valueOf() / 1000) <= parseInt(reservedFromData.valueOf() / 1000) || parseInt(checkoutDate.valueOf() / 1000) >= (parseInt(reservedToData.valueOf() / 1000)));
```

});

привела их к одному типу, и в результате надеялась получать данные исходя из этих условий. На деле же, выдает все, эти условия не срабатывают. Может кто-то знает почему?

Comment: попробуйте посмотреть вот этот [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/492994/5610621) и ответы к нему

Comment: @dinmep что конкретно "выдает" ?